# Azure Function ExecutionContext.InvocationId vs FunctionFilterContext.FunctionInstanceId

Tags: azure, azure-functions

`ExecutionContext.InvocationId` vs `FunctionFilterContext.FunctionInstanceId`

The `ExecutionContext` in Azure Function has a property `InvocationId`. In `IFunctionInvocationFilter.OnExecutedAsync(FunctionExecutedContext ...)` the `FunctionExecutedContext` has a property `FunctionInstanceId`, which is defined in its base class `FunctionFilterContext`.

- In the same call, are these two Ids the same?
- Are they unique for each call, or for each function instance?

Thanks if anyone can help!

Answer (score 2):

I was confused at first, but these are actually the same thing. They are both showing a unique identifier of function call, so they are the same for the same call, and different between calls.

The docs aren't great in this part, but you can compare [Retrieving information about the currently running function](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/wiki/Retrieving-information-about-the-currently-running-function)

> Provides the invocation ID, uniquely identifying the current invocation

with [FunctionExceptionContext source code](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host/Filters/FunctionExceptionContext.cs#L19)

> The instance ID for the function invocation

I actually ran a test and both properties gave me the same `Guid`.

Comment: Thanks for your updated answer. Yes the documentation isn't very helpful on this. And yes I did that test locally as well and it appeared to me they are the same. However, I am not sure if that will always remain the same when it's running on Azure. My understanding of the comment "the instance id for the function invocation" is that it's the function instance ID, but it does not say if the invocation id will always be the same as the instance ID.